# MetaPost: does btex ... etex support any LaTeX command?

Tags: formatting, diagrams, labels, text, metapost

I am running a MetaPost sample as follows:

```
beginfig(1);
label.(btex the \emph{sum} is $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}a_n$ etex, (3cm, 3cm));
endfig;
end;
```

by `mpost main.mp`. In the log there is a message

```
! ! Unable to read mpx file.
l.2 label.(btex
                the \emph{sum} is $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}a_n$ etex, (3c...
```

Without `\emph` command it works but with it there is the message. I thought any LaTeX command would be accepted in `btex ... etex` environment...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem seems to be in the creation of a (nonnecessary) `.aux` file.

This might require some intervention on the LaTeX side. Meanwhile, adding `\nofiles` seems to fix the issue. Also `\normalfont` is needed for this particular example (if you don't specify some document class in `verbatimtex...etex`.

```
verbatimtex \nofiles etex;
prologues:=3;
beginfig(1);
label.(btex \normalfont the \emph{sum} is $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}a_n$ etex, (3cm, 3cm));
endfig;
end;
```

(I added also `prologues:=3` in order to be able to preview a PDF file).

Calling

```bash
> mpost -tex=latex vladimir.mp
> epstopdf vladimir.1
```

produces

[image]

For instance,

```
erbatimtex \nofiles\documentclass{article}\usepackage{fourier} etex;
prologues:=3;
beginfig(1);
label.(btex the \emph{sum} is $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}a_n$ etex, (3cm, 3cm));
endfig;
end;
```

will produce

[image]

Comment: AFAIR metapost supports %&laetx within `verbatimtex ... etex` (which the has to be on several lines) saves on the `-tex=latex`

Comment: @daleif Yes, it does, you remember well

Comment: Haven't used metapost in yeears, but remember never having used `-tex=latex`

Comment: Could you explain why we had to make some extra settings? Because, by default, the content of ```btex...etex``` construction is not an arbitrary LaTeX code but mostly plain text or formulas? So that to make text formatting commands implementable we need some special preparation?

Comment: @Vladimir `\emph` is a specific LaTeX command, so you need to tell Metapost to use it for `btex...etex`. The need for `\nofiles` might have been arisen because of some change to the LaTeX kernel. I'm investigating it.

Comment: @Vladimir I confirm that at least `verbatimtex \nofiles\normalfont etex` is necessary (besides specifying `-tex=latex` in the command line or `%&latex` inside `verbatimtex...etex` together with the above instructions.

Comment: I have applied your solution, thank you. So the minimal and enough settings are ```verbatimtex \nofiles\normalfont etex``` (in *.mp) and ```-tex=latex``` (in cmd).

Comment: @Vladimir Yes, that's it.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the option of switching to `lualatex` for your document, then the OP example works "as expected".

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
label(btex the \emph{sum} is $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}a_n$ etex, (3cm, 3cm));
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

Compile this with `lualatex` to get this output directly, with no special flags or options needed:

[image]

The `luamplib` package automagically passes any `btex .... etex` tokens through the enclosing LaTeX environment, so you pick up all the same font settings and you can use all the same control sequence definitions.  There is (some) documentation [here](https://ctan.org/pkg/luamplib?lang=en).